# Join Query on WP_USERMETA Table

Tags: database, query, user-meta

I want to check if user time zone is perth and its belong from Group A.

MY QUERY IS NOT WORKING

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_users` AS t1 LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS t2 ON 
t1.ID=t2.user_id 
WHERE t2.meta_key='Time_Zone'
AND t2.meta_value = 'PERTH'
AND t2.meta_key='user_class_group'
AND t2.meta_value='Group A'
```

THIS QUERY IS WORKING IF I USED ON 01 AND

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_users` AS t1 LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS t2 ON 
t1.ID=t2.user_id 
WHERE (t2.meta_key='Time_Zone') 
AND t2.meta_value='PERTH'
```

[image]
TABLE WHICH I NEED TO CHECK

Comment: Have you tried using `WP_User_Query` instead? It's also possible to have taxonomies for users

Comment: no actually I've almost finish this through query just stuck on one step on query. can you please help me out to get achieve result through query

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot, but there's a very easy way to get this data in PHP code, you do not need to make a raw SQL query

Comment: can you guide me with WP_user_query?

Comment: You can start here:  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/
Try writing the query and then edit your question and someone can help you through the finer points.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function get_users_email ($time_zone_cont, $class_group){
        // Add Lisa's user id,  14, in an array.
        $exclude_list = array(  );
        $Time_Zone = $time_zone_cont;
        $user_class_group = $class_group;
        $args = array(
            // 'role' => 'Editor',
            // 'exclude' => $exclude_list,
             'meta_query' => array(
                // 'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'Time_Zone',
                    'value'   => $Time_Zone,
                    'compare' => '='
                ),
                array(
                    'key'     => 'user_class_group',
                    'value'   => $user_class_group,
                    'compare' => '='
                )
                )
        );
         
        // Custom query.
        $my_user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
         
        // Get query results.
        $results = $my_user_query->get_results();
         
        // Check for editors
        if ( ! empty( $results ) ) {
                foreach ( $results as $result ) {
                    // Get each editor's data.
                    $output = get_userdata( $result->ID );
                    // Show editor's name.
                 $get_output[] = $output->user_email;  
                }
                
                
        }

return $get_output;
}
```

Achieve the desired result through  `WP_User_Query` class thanks @Tony Djukic and @ Tom J Nowell